# The Facebook sharer's "locale" parameter doesn't work

Tags: locale, facebook-sharer

Until now, when i want to share something in Facebook with a specific language(for example, french), i use the locale parameter, like this:

http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?locale=fr_FR

But now, the Facebook sharer ignores the locale parameter in the URL and always display the share pop up with the user language.

Anyone knows anything about?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the facebook sharer always uses en as the default locale to parse your website. But if you want to share your own website, there is a workaround to show the locale as you wish.

If you want to share the link: http://www.yourwebsite.com/something with different locales:

1. Add a parameter to pass the locale information: http://www.yourwebsite.com/something?l=fr_FR and share this link with the sharer.
2. Your website change its locale according to this parameter.

Not pretty but it works.